# Unexpected end_of_input, expecting ';' mysql

Tags: mysql

I dont know how to fix it:

```
drop trigger if exists insertusuario;
CREATE TRIGGER insertusuario
BEFORE INSERT ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW
begin
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ',new.nombre,'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ',new.contraseña,' WITH GRANT OPTION;
end;
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing application code (variables like `new.nombre`) and MySQL code, and if so that you're making a mistake around the `%` character.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Grant` command statement preparation like below:

```
   SELECT
     CONCAT( 'GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ''',
             new.nombre,
             '''@''%'' IDENTIFIED BY ''',
             new.contraseña,
             ''' WITH GRANT OPTION'
     ) INTO @temp_grant_sql_string;
```

Use prepared statement to execute this generated grant statement;

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @temp_grant_sql_string;
EXECUTE stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt; -- or drop prepare stmt;
```

Let me hope you know about `delimiter` part before registering a stored procedure.

Use: `delimiter $$` before trigger definition. And,
use: `delimiter ;` after trigger definition, to reset to default.

Finally, your trigger should be reading like this:

```
delimiter $$;

drop trigger if exists insertusuario
$$

CREATE TRIGGER insertusuario BEFORE INSERT ON usuario
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SELECT
     CONCAT( 'GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ''',
             new.nombre,
             '''@''%'' IDENTIFIED BY ''',
             new.contraseña,
             ''' WITH GRANT OPTION'
     ) INTO @temp_grant_sql_string;

   PREPARE stmt FROM @temp_grant_sql_string;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; -- or DROP PREPARE stmt;

END;

$$

delimiter ;
```